# Custom Colors Bar Graph Plotly - R

Tags: r, graph, colors, plotly

I have a grouped bar graph and I am trying to customize the colors for each of the variables or columns. I was able to to it for the first, but if I tired that with the second a third bar would populate.

What would be the best method to go about this? 
My code is below:

```
SpendOpt <- plot_ly(
  x= TV_Attribute_Solver$Channel,
  y= TV_Attribute_Solver$Current.spend,
  name="Current  Spend",
  type = "bar",
  marker = list(color = "#33aFFF"))


SpendOpt <- add_trace(
  SpendOpt, 
  x=TV_Attribute_Solver$Channel,
  y=TV_Attribute_Solver$Optimized.Spend,
  name = "Optimized Spend",
  type = "bar"
)
```

the data would be:

```
> dput(data)

structure(list(Channel = c("13th Street", "7 TWO Sydney", "7MATE Sydney", 
"Arena", "ATN-7 Sydney", "BBC Knowledge"), Current.spend = c(2782L, 
2075L, 990L, 1194L, 32534L, 356L), Optimized.Spend = c(3060.2, 
2282.5, 891, 1313.4, 33410.127, 391.344)), .Names = c("Channel", 
"Current.spend", "Optimized.Spend"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

> data
        Channel Current.spend Optimized.Spend 
1   13th Street          2782        3060.200  
2  7 TWO Sydney          2075        2282.500   
3  7MATE Sydney           990         891.000  
4         Arena          1194        1313.400   
5  ATN-7 Sydney         32534       33410.127   
6 BBC Knowledge           356         391.344
```

Also is there a way to create more space between the two groupings? 
thank you

Comment: I hadn't used `plotly` for `R`, so thanks for the indirect prompting! I was going to fiddle with this question, but the dataset you're using isn't clear. If it's local, please post a reproducible example so others can try to assist. Maybe use `mtcars` for example? Also, I find it desirable to post what you get vs. what you want. Your question asks about color, but you end with asking about "more space." More distinction between colors? More distance separation? Having a visual aid would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you and I have updated the question with the data set. The bars would be Current Spend and Optimized Spend and I would like for each column to have its own customized color. I was able to do it for the first bar with marker, unfortunately I could not succeed for the second bar.

Comment: 1) I added a `dput()` version (easier than manually typing in your table view) and 2) I just get pairs of blue bars wen I run the above. Should I see something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I'd just go ahead and add an answer. I've only used `plotly` for the first time ever, so I'm not really sure how the code you have works. That said, if I understand the question correctly, you want colors based on whether or not it's `Optimized.spend` or `Current.spend`. I just extended what you did above to the second part, and I get this:

```
SpendOpt <- plot_ly(
   x= data$Channel,
   y= data$Current.spend,
   name="Current  Spend",
   type = "bar",
   marker = list(color = "#33aFFF")
)


SpendOpt <- add_trace(
   SpendOpt, 
   x=data$Channel,
   y=data$Optimized.Spend,
   name = "Optimized Spend",
   type = "bar",
   marker = list(color = "#afafaf")
)

SpendOpt
```

I get this:

[image]

If that's what you expected, perhaps something else is going on with your setup. I don't see the mentioned "third bar." You might want to try `ls()` to see what variables you have created or double check something else.

If this *isn't* what you were trying to achieve, feel free to comment/clarify. This goes back to my suggestion in the comments that reproducible examples and visuals speak so much louder than words: take a screenshot of what you get and mark it up with labels or hand-drawn corrections in the editor of your choice, for example.